# Safari 5.0 Extension Scripts Won't Run on Local Files

Tags: javascript, windows, safari-extension, safari

I wrote a very simple extension for Safari 5 that only outputs a single log message from a start script. This is the start script:

console.log('start script running');

If I go to any internet page (eg. http://www.yahoo.com) the log message appears in the error console. But if I open any local html page no log message appears. By local I mean on my local machine. It's like my start script never gets run for local pages (eg. C:/blank.html).

Is there a permission setting I'm overlooking or is this a feature of Safari 5?

Brent

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: I only have a passing familiarity with the Safari extension system. I work on Google Chrome which is based on Webkit. Safari is also based on webkit.

In a Google Chrome extension, you can inject a script into a local page using the `file://` permission. But I’m pretty sure there’s no analogue for Safari extensions.

The [Safari page on script injection](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html) also seems to say you can’t interact with local files:

“You cannot access resources on the user’s hard drive outside of the extensions folder.”

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to inject scripts on local files.

If you feel like it, you may complain at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).